# How can I use pdfk fill_form without writing to a temp file

Tags: mysql, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf, pdftk

I am trying to populate a pdf report with data from my mysql database. It works fine on my local machine but when I upload it to www.000webhost.com, the pdf document is not generated.

I know the document writes a temp file to my folder every time I click print report.Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work on the hosting provider and how I can fix this issue. I am under the impression that it is a security issue.

Do I have to write a temp file. Why couldn't I have used the $fdf variable to populate the report instead of the temporary file?

```
$fdf_fn= tempnam( '.', 'fdf' );
$fp= fopen( $fdf_fn, 'w' );
if( $fp ) {
    fwrite( $fp, $fdf );
    fclose( $fp );

//attachment for view
header(   'Content-type: application/pdf' );
header(   'Content-disposition: inline; filename=TEST.pdf');

passthru(   "pdftk ./../../reports/TEST.pdf fill_form ". $fdf_fn.' output - flatten' );

unlink( $fdf_fn ); // delete temp file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work on the hosting provider and how
>   I can fix this issue. I am under the impression that it is a security
>   issue.

My *guess* is you simply don't have write permission in the required directory.

You create your temporary file in the current working directory (`.`). Depending on your hosting provider and the HTTP server configuration, the current working directory is not necessary what you think nor  writable. Especially since your program will probably run with the *www* or *nobody* identity.

I assume you have to create and then adjust the permissions on your "temporary" directory -- or use a "world writable" location such as `/tmp`.

Finally, you have a relative path that move "upward" in your program: `./../../reports/TEST.pdf fill_form` There is little chances for this to be valid on your hosting...

Comment: I did a little further research and it said that the webhosts automatically disables the passthru function. How can I enable this?

Comment: @user2635901 As this is a much more specific topic, I think you should (1) check if this has already been answered, (2a) if yes, *answer yourself* here by providing a link to the relevant discussion, (2b) if not post a *new question*.